# Wordpress. How can i rewrite one url with params to another pretty url?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite url from

```
https://example.com/arenda-avtomobilej-2/?min_price=300&max_price=1200&limo-vip=on&wwf=on
```

to

```
https://example.com/arenda-avtomobilej-2/somepage/
```

and save all get params to query vars.

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

**add_rewrite_rule()** [[see]](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/)

Adds a rewrite rule that transforms a URL structure to a set of query vars.

```php
add_action('init',  function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'min_price/([0-9]+)[/]?$', 'index.php?min_price=$matches[1]', 'top' );
} );

// https://example.com/arenda-avtomobilej-2/min_price/800
```

[[See also]](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/)